# Does time complexity change based on parameters?

Tags: c, time-complexity

If my function `void foo(n)` has a time complexity of O(n), and I have a function call `foo(4)`, would I say that the time complexity of `foo(4)` is O(4)?

Comment: Do you also understand that O(4) = O(1)?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the complexity of the function doesn't change depending of the parameters inserted, since it has been calculated over that parameter. In this case, if the complexity is O(n), over the parameter of the function (in you case, 4). Let's say that your function contains a for loop. Let's see an example in pseudo-code:

```
fun foo(int n) {
    for int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        print(i);
    }
}
```

This function prints the numbers from 0 to n. Since increasing n only increases the number of elements linearly, the function is O(n) independently of the value of n.

Another example in pseudo-code:

```
fun foo(int n) {
    for int i = 0; i < 2^n; i++) {
        print(i);
    }
}
```

In this case, the function prints the values from 0 to 2^n. Increasing n increases the number of elements exponentially, so the function is O(2^n). Changing the value of n does not change the complexity of the function.

But what happens if we have a function like this one?:

```
fun foo(int n, boolean b) {
    if(b == true) {
        for int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            print(i);
        }
    } else {
        for int i = 0; i < 2^n; i++) {
            print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the complexity of the function is O(n) if b is true, and O(2^n) if b is false. So, yes, the complexity of the function can change depending of the value of the parameters of the function, **only** if that parameter is not the selected for calculating the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Using Big-O notation will give you the notion how the time will increase with the n input. In this case, if foo() have always the same argument, the behavior will be constant. But keep this in mind, almost metrics used to measure complexity on time or/and memory only makes sense for a big n, because when the input is small the performance will be anyway high. So, in Big-O, you will look to your fucntion for an increasing n, then will be measurable and comparable.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The big O of n (O (n)) notation allows to obtain an order of n for the execution time of your algorithm depending on the increase of n during the function. For example, if the complexity of your algorithm (foo(n)) is in order of (n ^ 2) (O(n²)) then in the worst case (when your algorithm performs a maximum of loop turns), n which is a variable which represents the size of the input data will be in order of n ^ 2. I hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

No.

O(n) simply means that as `n` gets large, the time it takes the function to execute is proportional to `n`; In other words, it's a *qualitative* statement, not a quantitative one.  The time complexity of `foo` is O(n) whether the input is `4`, `4000`, `4000000`, or `4000000000`; all O(n) says is that the runtime grows linearly with `n`.

O(4) implies that the runtime is *constant* regardless of the size of the input - it's equivalent to writing O(1).  Your function cannot be both O(n) and O(4).

Comment: I’m not sure if they’re asking about the call `foo(4)` or something else, but if it’s the call, “no” isn’t correct.

Comment: to reply to Ry-, I am indeed asking specifically about the call `foo(4)`